# How can I debug my MacOSX application after compiling. Using PYQT5 for Gui and PY2APP to compile

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5

I'm currently working on a standalone MacOsx application programmed in Python3 with Pyqt5 gui. **My question is: How can I know what is crashing my app after compiling it.**

**Note: My app runs perfectly fine if I test it from terminal, but when I compile it, it crashes.**

I'm compiling it in the following way:

```
py2applet --make-setup main.py
python3 setup.py py2app
```

And then running it directly from the Dist file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can secondary click on the compiled application and click on the “Show Package Contents” option, this will bring you into the package. After going into the package, go to Contents/MacOS/YOUR-APP-NAME and click on run the unix executable to see the terminal output and have a look at what is going wrong.